# NHibernate where restrictions with an alias

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I'm trying to do a query *where* `someProperty.contains(string) || otherProperty.contains(string)` so I found the following:

```
.where(
 restrictions.on<type>(x => x.property).IsLike(string) ||
 restrictions.on<type>(x => x.prop2).IsLike(string)
)
```

however, I have an alias before this where for one of the properties for a join:

```
session.QueryOver<Trade>()
   .JoinAlias(x => x.TradeType, () => ttypeAlias)
   .Where(
       Restrictions.On<Trade>(c => c.Nickname).IsLike("%" + searchString + "%") ||
       Restrictions.On<TradeType>(() => ttypeAlias.TradeTypeName).IsLike("%" + searchString + "%") ||
   )
```

but I'm getting an error on the restriction line with the alias:

> delegate type does not accept 0 arguments

```
() => ttypeAlias.TradeTypeName
```

how do I incorporate this alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the syntax of the **`.On()`** used above:

```
/// <summary>
/// Build an ICriterion for the given property
/// </summary>
/// <param name="expression">lambda expression identifying property</param>
/// <returns>returns LambdaRestrictionBuilder</returns>
public static LambdaRestrictionBuilder On<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    ExpressionProcessor.ProjectionInfo projection = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberProjection(expression.Body);
    return new LambdaRestrictionBuilder(projection);
}
```

And that give us the answer:

> passed expression **must** have **one** argument (which does not have to be used)

**The syntax, which will work**, could be like this:

```
// no argument - it is wrong
// Restrictions.On<TradeType>(() => ttypeAlias.TradeTypeName)...

// here we expect one argument, and naming his lo-dash - is convention to say
// it won't be used, it is there just to fulfill all the rules
Restrictions.On<TradeType>(_ => ttypeAlias.TradeTypeName)...
```